# Can not restart vsftpd service through cron

Tags: 14.04, cron, vsftpd

On **Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS** I'm using [a script](https://github.com/ifaist0s/vesta-server-ssl-cert) to restart some services, when the TLS certificate that is being used is renewed. The script is run through root's crontab. Any change is TLS certificate triggers the commands to restart the services and activate the new certificate.

When the command `service vsftpd restart` is executed, cron daemon logs the following error: `vsftpd: unrecognized service`

Needless to say that `service vsftpd restart` works as expected when run on root's command line.

I also noticed that vsftpd does not appear in the list of services when running `service --status-all`

Crontab for root

```
14 7 * * * /root/vesta-server-ssl-cert.sh
```

**Question**: What is the correct command to be placed inside a script for restarting vsftpd service through root's crontab?

Comment: Can we see the `vesta-server-ssl-cert.sh` script's contents?

Comment: And what does `service vsftpd status` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with other services some time ago; resolved it by using initctl and didn't dig deeper to find out what was going on. So try:

```
/sbin/initctl restart vsftpd
```

it should work.

Oh, I hate these "this works, don't know why" answers, but that's all I have for the moment.

Edit:
Ok, now I feel better. `service` is a shell script, and it needs to have /sbin in the PATH environment, otherwise it can't find stop and start binaries it maps "restart" to. Then it uses /etc/init.d/ script, which it can't find, so it reports "unrecognized service"

TomTomTom

Comment: **Thank you!** I confirm that the use of /sbin/initctl restart vsftpd works perfectly for me :)